# Docker PHP and FreeTDS -cannot find freetds in know installation directories

Tags: php, docker, freetds

I'm trying to create my first image, which I forked from someone else, and I'm running into an issue where the build fails. Looks like the error is here

```
[91mconfigure: error: Cannot find FreeTDS in known installation directories
[0m
no
checking for PDO_DBLIB support via FreeTDS... yes, shared
```

Docker File

```
FROM php:5.6.30-apache

ENV DOWNLOAD_URL https://www.limesurvey.org/stable-release?download=2044:limesurvey2647%20170404targz
#php extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql pdo_dblib pdo_pgsql \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        freetds-bin \
        freetds-dev \
        freetds-common \
        libct4 \
        libsybdb5 \
        tdsodbc \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libldap2-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libc-client-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    && docker-php-ext-install ldap \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos \
    && docker-php-ext-install imap \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \

    #Download and install LimeSurvey
    && curl -SL "$DOWNLOAD_URL" -o /tmp/lime.tar.gz \
    && tar xf /tmp/lime.tar.gz limesurvey --strip-components=1 -C /var/www/html \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && rm -f /tmp/lime.tar.gz \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/tmp \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/upload \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/application/config \
    && mkdir -p /var/lib/php5 \
    && chown www-data:www-data /var/lib/php5
```

The image is using PHP 5.6.30. How can I get this to see the freetds installation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to consider the correct installation order of dependent packages. Currently your `RUN` command installs `freetds-{bin,dev}` *after* the `docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql pdo_dblib pdo_pgsql` command. If you turn around the order of installation steps, the freetds files will be found. Example snippet:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        freetds-bin \
        freetds-dev \
        freetds-common \
        libct4 \
        libsybdb5 \
        tdsodbc \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libldap2-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libc-client-dev \
        ...
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql pdo_dblib pdo_pgsql \
        ...
```

That won't be enough, though. I got the following error:

```
configure: error: Could not find /usr/lib/libsybdb.a|so
```

You can find solutions to such issues via Google. In that special case you need to add a symlink as part of your `RUN` command (found at https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/issues/643#issuecomment-165447722):

```
ln -s /path/to/your/libsybdb.a /usr/lib/
```

Similar issues might arise while working through your Dockerfile.

For development I recommend to split the huge `RUN` command into several dedicated `RUN` commands so that you won't have to perform every step over and over again. When you're confident that the Dockerfile works, you can join the commands back into a single `RUN` command.

Comment: For me it was the "so" file that I needed to link like so:  `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsybdb.so /usr/lib/`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! With this and `docker-php-ext-install mssql` I was able to connect to sqlServer using PHP 5.6 from a Docker container.

Comment: A platform independent way of creating this symlink would be `dpkg -L freetds-dev | grep libsybdb.a | xargs -i ln -s {} /usr/lib`. i.e. look up the path where the installer put it and feed that into the ln command.